# How do I install HTTRACK (Offline browser) with apt-get?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

I'm trying to install httrack. I used this comnmand:

```
sudo apt-get httrack
```

with no luck.

How can I install?

Comment: "with no luck" Please [edit] your question to include the exact error message you get. REmember that we can't see your screen and fully rely on the information you include in your question body.

Comment: @gertvdijk It is pretty obvious the error here isn't it?

Comment: @Tim I don't see any error message reported. I do see an error in your command provided, but I don't know whether that was the exact command as entered by the OP in his terminal.

Answer (score 3):

It's

```
sudo apt-get install httrack
```

Note the `install` command before the package name parameter. See the [Man Page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man8/apt-get.8.html).

Comment: I'd give you a +1, but the question was just too simple :) But no matter. here is my +1.